# Instructions set for backup and restore of SQL Server's DB (changing .mdf and .log file)

Tags: sql-server, automation

I have a series of repetitive tasks here at work. One of these is the creation of new database from a template.

To achieve this we have a *master_db* database that act like a template and its location is something like `C:\Backup\master_db.bak`.

After the creation of a new database `new_db`, right-click on it and go through *Task->Restore->Database*. In the *General* tab I choose *From device* and then I set `C:\Backup\master_db.bak` as  restoring source. In the *Options* tab I'll choose *Overwrite existing database* and I also need to  change .mdf and .log file (currently `C:\SQLData\master_db.mdf` and `C:\SQLData\master_db_log.ldf` in `C:\SQLData\new_db.mdf` and `C:\SQLData\new_db_log.ldf`).

This iter is in working order but for automation sake I need to do this step through code. What should I do? What parameters needs my `RESTORE` command? What command should I use to properly set .mdf and .ldf files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
restore database new_db from disk = 'C:\Backup\master_db.bak'
with
    move '<data_file>' to 'C:\SQLData\new_db.mdf',
    move '<log_file>' to 'C:\SQLData\new_db_log.ldf',
    replace
```

You need to update `<data_file>` and `<log_file>` with the logical file names for these files. You should be able to see them in the GUI.

Comment: I suppose that logical names that are needed refears to master_db? Do you confirm?

Comment: Yes, the logical file names relate to that database. You can also find them like this: go into a database that you have already restored using your method, and run `sp_helpfile` in that database. The first column contains the name.